# HttpClient testing issue: No provider for HttpClient with nested services

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have a problem upgrading to HttpClient from Http in Angular 4. I have a service which has a nested reference to HttpClient. My structure looks like this:
My `TokenHandlerService` injects `MyHttpService` which injects Angulars `HttpClient`

Running the code snippets I found online looks like this:

```
let service: TokenHandlerService;
let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            HttpClientModule,
            HttpClientTestingModule
        ],
        providers: [
            TokenHandlerService,
            MyHttpService
        ]
    });
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.get(TokenHandlerService);
});
```

I want to test the TokenHandlerService, but running this I always end up in an 
`Error: No provider for HttpClient!`.

How can I pass the mocked HttpClient to deeper nested services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the [support team at github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21440) I was able to fix this by adding:

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

to my `test.ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing **HttpClientModule** from import statement?

because we already added **HttpClientTestingModule** for our test module